# Removing empty strings in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list in the form

```
lst = ['', 'how', '', 'are', 'you', '']
```

and want to convert it into

```
lst = ['how','are', 'you']
```

I have currently used the code `list(filter(None,lst))` but no changes are returned. How can i remove the empty strings?

Comment: list(filter(None,lst)) works for me.

Comment: filter is not something that works "in place" you need to assign that back to lst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code must works but an other solution is using lambdas:

```
lst = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', lst))
print(lst)
```

Output: ['how', 'are', 'you']

Comment: Thanks @dgrana. My list had white spaces within the empty strings. I ddnt write it well on the question. lst = [' ', 'how', ' ', 'are', 'you', ' ' ]. Your solution works well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A simple and possible solution is the following:

```
lst = ['', 'how', '', 'are', 'you', '']

lst = [element for element in lst if element != '']
```

Now, lst is ['how', 'are', 'you']

Comment: I love comprehensions. You might think about dropping the `!= ""` as it is not technically needed.

Comment: @JonSG it's helpful to mention _why_ it's not technically needed, because it's not immediately obvious if you don't already know it -- because [empty strings are falsy in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Answer (score 1):

Are you printing `lst` again? Your code works for me.

```
lst = ['', 'how', '', 'are', 'you', '']
lst = list(filter(None,lst))
print(lst)
```

outputs `['how', 'are', 'you']`

Comment: thanks for your replies. Actually my list is lst = [' ', 'how', ' ', 'are', 'you', ' ' ]. Notice the empty strings have a white space in between, and not as how i wrote in previously. filter function won't remove them. Should I assume that [' '] is not actually an empty string ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you forgot to make the filter to this kinda thing:

```
lst = ['', 'how', '', 'are', 'you', '']
lst = list(filter(None, lst))
print(lst)
```

you define the `list` as `list(filter(None, lst))`